# Difference equations in Symbolic Toolbox Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, symbolic-math, difference-equations

Can someone please tell me is there a way to solve [difference equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_equation) e.g:

```
y(k) = a1 * y(k-1) + a2 * y(k-2) + b0*u(k)
```

in Matlab using Symbolic Toolbox? I want to find explicit solution of this equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297473), there are 2 methods:

- Apply [Z transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/compute-z-transforms-and-inverse-z-transforms.html), solve for X(z), then find inverse Z transform look up tables if needed.
- Write y(n)=r^n, to get the auxiliary equation, solve for homogeneous part first.

  ```
  r^n = a1*r(n-1) + a2*r^(n-2)
  ```

Bottom line is, there isn't a good method to solve difference equations in Matlab now.